# Connect bitbucket project with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I tried adding a Bitbucket repository to Jenkins and it failed due to an error - see below. How Can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: So where are your credentials? You see the empty dropdown below? You supply a username but no password, right? Click the _Add_ button below and remove the username from the URL.

Comment: I don't understand how to do that. If you don't mind could you explain it in more details please.

Comment: I clicked add button > then i selected jenkins from the dropdown. after than a window appeared. it has following text fields
Domain - Global credential 
Kind - username with password
Scope - global(jenkins, nodes,items....)
Username
Password
ID
Description
Do i have to enter my bitbucket login username which is my email and bitbucket login password ? and what comes for the ID field ? and from where i can find the ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Enter your **BitBucket credentials** in the window which opens when you click on the "add" button. After they have been added you will be able to select them in the screen you are showing and it should all be fine.

Comment: Your answer is not clear, "I clicked add button > then i selected jenkins from the dropdown. after than a window appeared. it has following text fields Domain - Global credential Kind - username with password Scope - global(jenkins, nodes,items....) Username Password ID Description Do i have to enter my bitbucket login username which is my email and bitbucket login password ? and what comes for the ID field ? and from where i can find the ID ?"

Comment: id and description are not mandatory. Just put your email and password.

Comment: The ID is e.g. needed if you want to access credentials from a pipeline script. And yes, of course you enter your bitbucket credentials there. Description is optional.